# Java Web Application - LoadLibrary at Application Startup

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish, java-native-interface

I have developed an WebApplication with Java-Servlets. It is running in a GlassFish-Server (on a Windows-Plattform). Now I need to load a DLL with JNI. I use System.loadLibrary(dll) to do this. I am now searching the way, to load this Library at the Application-Startup so it can be used of all Application-Instances. My questions are now:

- How does I have to define such a Startup-Event and where to put it and what to configure, that it will be executed
- How does I have to implement this Startup-Event, that all instances of the WebApp can after use the loaded Library and how can I use it from my existing servlets

Thanks for you help.

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a `ServletContextListener` and upon receiving the `contextInitialized` event you could load the dll at that point.

If you are using Spring (even better) you could load the dll statically (upon Spring startup) and then use Spring to get the "handler" to the dll.

Note though that if you directly load the dll from your web application and the dll crashes your application will crash as well.

Perhaps you should consider (although it requires extra effort) loading via another process and use e.g. RMI to interact with the dll. So if the dll crashes your app still remains intact.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one more question about the ServletContextListener. I have now implemented it in my application. I think, this is wrong because it will be executed at glassFish-Startup and at Startup of my WebApp. But I don't know, where I have to put it in, that it will only be called at startup of glassFish - and how I can implement the Loading of my DLL's that they are accessible from all WebApp-Instances.

Comment: The `contextInitialized` is called when the web application is ready to service requests and is called automatically by the container when its own initialization is finished.So usually code that needs to be executed on application start up is placed there.What do you mean by all web app instances?You want to load the dll to be used by multiple web applications running in the same container?